# How do I reset autonumber field in access 2003?

Tags: microsoft-access

How do I reset autonumber field in access 2003?

Answer (score 2):

Use the "compact and repair" process. This will reset the auto increment back to 0 (**for empty tables** that is).  If the table is still populated with records you don't want to reset the counter i think...

It can be found under:
Tools >> Database Utilities >> Compact and Repair Database

Comment: It resets it only on an empty table and resets it to 1, not 0.

Comment: @David are you sure about that.  I am pretty sure it stores the current maximum ID.  When a new row is added it will be maxid+1.  If the value that was stored was **1** for a new/clean table then the first ID that gets assigned would be **2**.

Comment: It does not store the current max but the next value, i.e., the Seed value. The seed value never resets to 0 unless you do it in code.

Answer (score 1):

A quick "totu" here with few ways to reset it. From Microsoft KB:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/812718

"I can't paste it here since it's in french for me"... sorry!

Answer (score 0):

If you are having index problems or wish to reset an autonumber seed to a sepcific value for unusual reasons see [Set AutoNumbers to start from ...](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-26.html)